# JQuery Popup Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am kinda new to Javascript/JQuery programming and I have a simple question.

What I am trying to accomplish is making a 450 x 350px popup that shows on a 2 second delay. I think I have the structure down on how to make it delay and show up.

My real question is how do I add custom content to that popup box? Would I add my content in a div with an ID and then reference that ID in the JQuery code to make it pop up?

I'm just not sure where to go with this.

Let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: Also, if it helps, Im using the setTimeout function to make it show delayed. If there is a better approach, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: you could use [jQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Or you could make your own "popup" by styling a DIV in CSS

Comment: Thanks David. So when I style the div to my liking, I can just call that div(div ID??) and it will show the content that is in there?

Comment: The way I would do it is to have a css class like `.hide {display:none;}`, and add that class to your div in the html. Once you're ready to show your div, just use `$('#my-div').removeClass('hide')`. There are other ways to do it, but that one for sure keeps the div hidden until you're ready to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a `<div id="one" class="js-one"></div>`. You can change text content w/ jQuery using the id `$('#one').text("Hello")` or the class `$('.js-one').text("Hello")`; note that using the class will update all elements w/ that class. If your custom content includes HTML then you'll want to use jQuery's `html` method instead of `text`.

See: http://api.jquery.com/text/ and the docs for `.html()`

To show/hide the styled div, see: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ and the docs for `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: Ahh thank you for the information Jeremiah. I will look into these resources a little bit more.